# Funds was sent to my blockchain for the past 24 hours it’s not reflecting by

Tags: address

Funds was sent to my Bitcoin address since yesterday it been 24 hours the funds is not available in my blockchain wallet
Here is the address: bc1quu54az2v6rkfny77z2mu4c38ypsf4agml8zskw